Manga where MC wakes up/reincarnates and finds himself in a room with a shelf of books
As mentioned above, the only thing I remember is that he wakes up in a room with a shelf of books. I am pretty sure he stays the same as a person, so he is rather transferred instead of really reincarnated. There he finds a book he uses to learn magic (I think). I think the house he wakes up in is that of an old sage that has passed but im not sure about that. I also think he later on befriends with a monster, but that might just be my imagination.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. An incorrect answer is an excellent opportunity to [edit] more details in, e.g. "I know it can't be Isekai or Die because the protagonist was completely bald, and his first harem member was an oddly alluring penguin who Swahili."

I've closed your question as a Duplicate. It's not a censure, just a site policy regarding id answers referencing the same work.

It's not a 100% match, but it wasn't last time either. Could it be Tensei Kenja no Isekai Raifu ~Daini no Shokugyo wo Ete, Sekai Saikyou ni Narimashita aka My Isekai Life written by Shinkoshoto and illustrated by Huuka Kazabana. as per Isekai manga, MC reads books that give him all magical knowledge, tames hundreds of slimes, kills a dragon, becomes an adventurer?

Whether at the office or at home, corporate drone Yuji Sano works all the time. So when his home PC flashes a message about him being summoned to another world, Yuji restarts his machine ... only to find that he's inadvertently accepted the summons! Now in a fantasy world far removed from paperwork and computers, Yuji has just one thing on his mind: waking up from what he thinks is a dream and getting back to the mountain of work he left behind! But this other world has other plans for Yuji, who quickly discovers his Monster Tamer character class allows him to befriend slimes! And thanks to their number, those slimes help him absorb so much magical knowledge that he gains a second character class in the blink of an eye! How will Yuji wield his power now that he's the greatest sage the realm has ever known?! And what about all that paperwork?!

He wakes up in a forest, but shortly after finds the house full of books that grant him the secrets of magic.
 Click to enlarge
